# Laravel ORM Relationship

Tags: laravel, orm, relationship, belongs-to

Hello I have those 4 tables:

```
Products (id, name)

Params (id, name)

Product_Param (id, product_id, param_id)

Values (product_param_id, value)
```

I can get all product params:

```
public function params() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Param', 'product_param')->withPivot('id', 'type1_id', 'type2_id');
    }
```

Code:

```
foreach($products->params as $param) {
    var_dump($param)
}
```

And now I need to get param value.
I wrote stupid code like this:

```
public static function getPPV($product_id, $param_id) {

    $value = new \App\Models\ParamValue();
    $value->value =  NULL;
    $value->id = NULL;

    $pp = \App\Models\ProductParam::where('product_id','=',$product_id)->where('param_id','=',$param_id)->first();

    if (!$pp) return $value;


    $ppv = \App\Models\ProductParamValue::where('product_param_id','=',$pp->id)->first();


    if (!$ppv) return $value;

    $value->value = $ppv->productvalue->value;
    $value->id = $ppv->productvalue->id;


    return $value;
}
```

It works but I want use better solution with ORM. Param model:

```
public function val() {
    $p = $this->hasOne('App\Models\ProductParam')->orderBy('id','desc')->where('product_id','=',$this->product_id);
    $ppv = $p->getResults()->hasOne('App\Models\ProductParamValue');
    $val =   $ppv->getResults()->belongsTo('App\Models\ParamValue','param_value_id');

    return $val;
}
```

But in Param Model I can't get Product ID *->where('product_id','=',$this->product_id)* (we have Product_Param (id, product_id, param_id) and I get all rows from  Product_Param.

Please help to write ORM.

Answer (score 0):

This may be not what you're looking for, but have you tried implementing the `value` column in the Values table to be its own column in the Product_Params table? Then you could access each of the values by saying:

```
foreach($products->params as $param) {
    var_dump($param->pivot->value);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can. I'm a team lead in the project but if I want rename column product_id to id (smile) it's a pain, because business don't understand why I want to do it.